# PuTTY tunnels and IP address translation

Tags: windows, networking, putty, routing, tunnel

I hope it's simple. I'm tied to the following situation:

1. A tight VPN that allows me to access only port 22 of my server, and has to be via IP address (no DNS)
2. My happy [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) tunnels that gives me access to all other ports in that server. For this example let's connect to oracle on 1521. So my PuTTY has: L1521 to 127.0.0.1:1521. Grand, toad wroks.
3. An annoying Windows XP application which I really need and there's no other option. It connects via port 57001, so I have another PuTTY map and it works fine.

When does trouble happen:

This application connects to the server and fetches some other connection data. Actually, it fetches the database connection for itself, something like *10.222.12.13:1521*. But as I said, that server will only accept on port 22, thus my PuTTY tunnels.

It's worth mentioning that I cannot change the connection data it fetches.

I reckon if I could tell my Windows installation "hey when something asks you 10.222.12.13 send it to 127.0.0.1 instead", would do it. I just don't know how. The [hosts](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHosts_(file)&ei=RyB9TJrdLqWhOJDY5YIE&usg=AFQjCNEJMNj89vV-DYw2aVIlyUt_8UuNQg) file does it for host names, what about concrete IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a route to 10.222.12.13 via the command prompt?

Here are the [instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/route.mspx)

Answer (score 0):

> The hosts file does it for host names, what about concrete IPs addresses?

It works for concrete IP addresses too.

Comment: meh.. no.. it didn't work :(

Comment: Try the different troubleshooting steps suggested in http://superuser.com/questions/175183/hosts-file-not-working-correctly/175207#175207