# Editing hosts file to block sites not working

Tags: windows-7, hosts-file

I put these lines in my `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 www.cnn.com
127.0.0.1 cnn.com
127.0.0.1 facebook.com
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 www.hotnews.ro
127.0.0.1 hotnews.ro
```

And I still manage to access these websites.

I restarted my computer, cleared the cache, different browsers, nothing works.

I am not using proxies. I use Windows 7/64 bit.

I flashed my DNS: `ipconfig /flushdns` and when I ping the cnn.com I get reply from `157.166.226.25`

What else can I do? Maybe there are some programs to modify the hosts and would work with them.

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: @gronostaj Windows 7

Comment: When you say `etc/hosts`, you mean `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, right?

Comment: host file to block sites?

Comment: @aecolley yes, it is that file. I think it is something in my configuration. I tried on another laptop and it works fine in blocking those websites with the same file. Could it be because of dual boot?

Comment: @BenPlont Actually I need to redirect a website of mine to the IP of my new hosting server and DNS changes take up to 24h, so I wanted to test it locally sooner. But it seems that my hosts file is not working, since it cannot even block websites.

Comment: @Claudiu it's not working for another reason.  Ping localhost now that you have defined it after a DNS flush

Comment: @Ramhound I get reply from `::1:`

Comment: @Claudiu - That's an iPv6 address, its also, the correct IPv6 response.

Comment: Why would you change the hosts file to achieve what you want? You can make changes in your local dns server, that will reach your clients.

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious, you are specifying specific websites, with non wildcards.  Is www.facebook.com being blocked while www.login.facebook.com still accesible?

Comment: try *.facebook.com

Comment: The following questions are all related.
· [Editing hosts file to block sites not working](https://superuser.com/q/796630)
· [Why does the hosts file in Windows 10 no longer block YouTube?](https://superuser.com/q/1410860)
· [My host file is not working on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1509619)
· [Hosts File not working correctly](https://superuser.com/q/175183)
· [Domain blocked in Windows hosts file, but the site is still accessible](https://superuser.com/q/1583508)
· [Blocking a website using "hosts" file doesn't work when using a VPN](https://superuser.com/q/1615339)

Answer (score 3):

To block sites you need to list all the domain-names, for sites like facebook and youtube that's a really big list of names and ip-addresses. I'll copy the code that I used for blocking youtube beneath.

```
Subdomain   IP Address
127.0.0.1   host.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   host.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   mx.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   216.58.192.206
127.0.0.1   mx.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   216.58.192.238
127.0.0.1   mx.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   172.217.0.14
127.0.0.1   mx.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   172.217.6.14
127.0.0.1   mx.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   172.217.9.46
127.0.0.1   mx.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   216.58.192.174
127.0.0.1   172.217.6.110   
127.0.0.1   172.217.4.46
127.0.0.1   172.217.1.46    
127.0.0.1   172.217.8.174
127.0.0.1   172.217.8.206
127.0.0.1   216.58.192.142
127.0.0.1   216.58.216.78
127.0.0.1   172.217.4.78
127.0.0.1   216.58.216.238
127.0.0.1   74.125.126.129
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   mx.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   2607:f8b0:4009:803:0:0:0:200e
127.0.0.1   admin.youtube.com   
127.0.0.1   2607:f8b0:4001:c1d:0:0:0:81
127.0.0.1   http.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   http.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   mx0.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   mx0.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   administration.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   administration.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   development.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   development.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   svn.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   svn.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   id.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   id.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   mx1.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63  
127.0.0.1   mx1.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   ads.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   172.217.8.174
127.0.0.1   devsql.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   devsql.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   syslog.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   syslog.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   ads.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   2607:f8b0:4001:c1d:0:0:0:66
127.0.0.1   adserver.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   adserver.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   images.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   images.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   mysql.youtube.com   
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   mysql.youtube.com   
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   devtest.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   devtest.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   info.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   info.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   172.217.9.46
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   216.58.192.174
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   172.217.6.110
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   172.217.4.46
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   172.217.1.46
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   172.217.8.174
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   172.217.8.206
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   216.58.192.142
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   216.58.216.78
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   172.217.4.78
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   216.58.216.238
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   216.58.192.206
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   216.58.192.238
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   172.217.0.14
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   172.217.6.14
127.0.0.1   alerts.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   alerts.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   dhcp.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   dhcp.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   test1.youtube.com   
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   test1.youtube.com   
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   news.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   2607:f8b0:4009:803:0:0:0:200e
127.0.0.1   internal.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   internal.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   noc.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   noc.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   alpha.youtube.com   
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   alpha.youtube.com   
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   direct.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   direct.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   test2.youtube.com   
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63  
127.0.0.1   test2.youtube.com   
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   internet.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   internet.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   ns.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   ns.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   ap.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   ap.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   dmz.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   dmz.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   testing.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   testing.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   intra.youtube.com   
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   intra.youtube.com   
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   ns0.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   ns0.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   apache.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   apache.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   dns.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   dns.youtube.com 
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   upload.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1   172.217.8.175
127.0.0.1   upload.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   2607:f8b0:4009:803:0:0:0:200f
127.0.0.1   intranet.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   intranet.youtube.com    
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   ns1.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   ns1.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   app.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   app.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   dns0.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   dns0.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   vm.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   vm.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   ipv6.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   ipv6.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   ns2.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   ns2.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   apps.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   apps.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   dns1.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   dns1.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   vnc.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   vnc.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   lab.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   lab.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   ns3.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   ns3.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   appserver.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   appserver.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   dns2.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   dns2.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   ldap.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   ldap.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   aptest.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   aptest.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   download.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   download.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   vpn.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   vpn.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   linux.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   linux.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   ops.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   ops.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   auth.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   auth.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   en.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   en.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   web.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   web.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   local.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   local.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   oracle.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   oracle.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   backup.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   backup.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   erp.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   erp.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   web2test.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   web2test.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   log.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   log.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   owa.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   owa.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   beta.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   beta.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   eshop.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   eshop.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   whois.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   whois.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   pbx.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   pbx.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   blog.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   blog.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   exchange.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   exchange.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   wiki.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   wiki.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   172.217.8.174
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   172.217.8.206
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   216.58.192.142
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   216.58.216.78
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   172.217.4.78
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   216.58.216.238
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   216.58.192.206
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   216.58.192.238
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   172.217.0.14
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   172.217.6.14
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   172.217.9.46
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   216.58.192.174
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   172.217.6.110
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   172.217.4.46
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   172.217.1.46
127.0.0.1   s3.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   s3.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   f5.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   f5.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   2607:f8b0:4009:803:0:0:0:200e
127.0.0.1   secure.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   secure.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   chat.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   chat.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   fileserver.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   fileserver.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   www2.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   www2.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   server.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   server.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   citrix.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   citrix.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   firewall.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   firewall.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   xml.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   xml.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   main.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   main.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   shop.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   shop.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   cms.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   172.217.8.174
127.0.0.1   forum.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   forum.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   cms.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   2607:f8b0:4001:c1d:0:0:0:66
127.0.0.1   manage.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   manage.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   sip.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   sip.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   corp.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   74.125.126.129
127.0.0.1   corp.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   2607:f8b0:4001:c1d:0:0:0:81
127.0.0.1   mgmt.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   mgmt.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   crs.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   crs.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   mirror.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   mirror.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   sql.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   sql.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   cvs.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   cvs.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   git.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   git.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   mobile.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   mobile.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   squid.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   squid.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   database.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   database.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   gw.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   gw.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   help.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   172.217.12.100
127.0.0.1   monitor.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   monitor.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   ssh.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   ssh.youtube.com     
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   db.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   db.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   help.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   2607:f8b0:4002:811:0:0:0:2004
127.0.0.1   mssql.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   mssql.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   ssl.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   ssl.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   demo.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   demo.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   helpdesk.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   helpdesk.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   mta.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   mta.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   dev.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
127.0.0.1   dev.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.254.63
127.0.0.1   home.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   198.105.244.63
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but some suggestions:

- Remove any extensions you might have on your file.
- Make sure you have this line somewhere in your file (preferably at top)

  `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Edit: Should be localhost not localhosts (no 's' at the end)

Edit 2: Here's a pretty complete list of hostfile related info on serverfault.  Maybe it'll help: https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot

Comment: What does that line do?

Comment: Not a 100% clear, but I think it is what creates the loop back to the "local host" page when you try to access facebook or whatever.  It's mentioned on several sites, and I think is defaulted in the file, so he probably has it.  Wikipedia has some additional info on it.

Comment: Default file has it commented out with a note: `# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.`, and it's `localhost` not `localhosts`, and it doesn't matter because OP isn't trying to resolve `localhost`.

Comment: No, I didn't have it. I put it, but does nothing. But it is written  `#localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself`.

Comment: This does not exactly answer the question.  Doing this only defines the URL "localhost" is bound to 127.0.0.1 but the hosts file is NOT designed to block websites

Comment: Claudiu, as gronostaj pointed out, localhosts should be localhost.  @Ramhound, I have used it in the past for blocking sites, and it is a nice trick.  My "answer" is just some suggestions, since I don't really know a lot about the host file except for what I just looked up as common host file problems.  I would have preferred to commented them in, but don't have the rep for that.  Guess I won't take that chance again, considering the downvote.

Comment: As I point out.  The reason for the downvote is that this foes not solve the authors problem because localhost isn't even a valid domain and having it or not having it doesn't invalidate those entries in the hosts file which the author already attempt and I the question states ( does not work )

Answer (score 1):

possible issues, corruption in file. Editor(notepad) saving it with a .txt extension. Editing the wrong file location.  to cover these issues

- rename current host file

and then use
 -  notepad %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

to make getting correct file
enter one line from your list, save and check folder to make sure did not save it with a .txt
 then try it with a ping.

Comment: I can concur, sometimes you need to run Notepad or Notepad++ as Admin, then only edit Hosts file or else it saves as .TXT file which inturn gets ignored. Way around it, copy hosts file onto desktop edit it, when saving in Notepad choose Save As... then in File Type type choose All filetypes, and specify the name as "hosts" without any extension, then save it, then copy it over  back into etc\ and overwriting it.