# Block page with windows hosts file

Tags: windows-7, blocking, hosts, hosts-file

I want to use the windows 7 [hosts](https://superuser.com/questions/796630/editing-hosts-file-to-block-sites-not-working) file (in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) to block this page :

```
play.chessbase.com/js/apps/playchess
```

However, it is not working despite all these entries:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 http://play.chessbase.com/js/apps/playchess/
127.0.0.1 play.chessbase.com/js/apps/playchess
127.0.0.1 play.chessbase.com/js/apps/playchess/
127.0.0.1 chessbase.com
127.0.0.1 www.chessbase.com
127.0.0.1 80.237.188.82
127.0.0.1 http://en.playchess.com/
127.0.0.1 5.35.251.47
127.0.0.1 Play.chessbase.com
```

When I add

```
127.0.0.1 www.altavista.com
```

The site is sucessfully blocked. However, it does not work for the other link above.

How can I block this page?

Comment: Why can't you block it at the router level and/or DNS server level?  OpenDNS allows you to block domains and is far more effective then using the hosts file.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not want to install an extra program, I dont know how to block it on "router level and/or DNS server level"?

Comment: I gave you an example of a DNS service that has the feature your looking for.  How you do it at the router level entirely depends on your hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When blocking a site in your hosts file, don't give it a place to go.

```
0.0.0.0 play.chessbase.com
```

None of the other entries you have there work, please remove them.  You can't reference a http:// address or URL in your hosts file.

Comment: This solution blocks "play.chessbase.com", but I want to block "play.chessbase.com/js/apps/playchess" (I can still access this link)?

Comment: If you are looking to block layer 7 you will need a software or hardware solution to actually block the URL.  This can't be done with a hosts file.  You will need a content filter of some kind.

Comment: @emcor - If you redirect the domain name `play.chessbase.com` you will concomitantly block any paths appended to it, such as `play.chessbase.com/js/apps/playchess`, but other domains, such as `chessbase.com` and `www.chessbase.com` will be unaffected unless you redirect them individually. For more comprehensive control, you may be able to use your firewall settings or the parental controls in your security software.

Comment: I still can access "play.chessbase.com/js/apps/playchess" (while "play.chessbase.com" is correctly blocked)?

Comment: If you block access to the site then the page can't be displayed.  If you have a cached connection you will still be connected, you would need to close the web browser and reopen it to test.

Comment: I reopened the browser and it is still displaying the site (play.chessbase.com/js/apps/playchess), maybe because it is a Java App. Did you try it on your browser?

Comment: If you're running a java app from your machine it might be hard coded with IP addresses.  You would need to remove the java app, then try to go to the page.

Comment: ok now I see: I was logged in with a user account on that page, after I manually logged out and reloaded the page it is now blocked.

Comment: Gotta love chasing ghosts.