# Blocking a website using "hosts" file doesn't work when using a VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I'm trying to use Windows' hosts file to block a specific website, but my problem is that while using a VPN it doesn't get blocked at all, and without a VPN it gets blocked on Chrome but not on Firefox.

I did the same setup using the same hosts file and VPN on another PC and it worked perfectly there; consistently blocking the website, but it has the problem I stated on my own PC.

I already tried:

1. `ipconfig /flushdns`
2. Double-checked `hosts` file for syntax errors or whitespaces.
3. Checked for permission problems.

Comment: Are there any cache data from browser ? Remove the cache data from the browser and check again. 
Then ping one of the domains that you changed and see if it returns the 127.0.0.1. If the ping doesn't return 127.0.0.1, the issue might be related with hostfile. If the ping works, clear browser cache and check again. For your reference:https://superuser.com/questions/1509619/my-host-file-is-not-working-on-windows-10

Comment: The following questions are all related.
· [Editing hosts file to block sites not working](https://superuser.com/q/796630)
· [Why does the hosts file in Windows 10 no longer block YouTube?](https://superuser.com/q/1410860)
· [My host file is not working on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1509619)
· [Hosts File not working correctly](https://superuser.com/q/175183)
· [Domain blocked in Windows hosts file, but the site is still accessible](https://superuser.com/q/1583508)
· [Blocking a website using "hosts" file doesn't work when using a VPN](https://superuser.com/q/1615339)